# ValueError at /admin/zinnia/entry/add/ in Zinnia?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, zinnia

When adding an entry using the admin site in Zinnia app in Django I get the following error?

```
ValueError at /admin/zinnia/entry/add/

too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your using correct versions of dependencies for Zinnia.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with categories and how it is displayed when you add or edit entry if you use Django 1.11. Fastest workaround is to downgrade Django to 1.10.

@weather api suggested to look into dependencies, but setup.py doesn't even mention Django package by itself, so by default Django 1.11 will be installed.

Comment: Thank you @iustitia